# ¿Como obtengo la cadena numerica dentro de una cadena que tienes otros caracteres extras?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, regex

Lo que quiero hacer es mediante c# separar mis chars que estan de mas en mi cadena de tipo string el formato con el que llegan de la BD es `$MXN0.00` y con ese formato no se puede hacer operaciones de aritmética, por lo que necesito solamente obtener el valor numérico completo sea cual sea aparte de que el prefijo `$MXN` cambia dependiendo de la región.

Código Actual

```
        str = readerExterno[1].ToString();
        tarifaProveedor =  Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value;
        calculoProv = float.Parse(tarifaProveedor) *elementDB.Horas;
```

El código de arriba solo me obtiene un digito y no el resto de ellos, lo intente con .split pero como el prefijo cambia no sabria como detectarlo de forma dinámica.

si el valor es muy grande puede venir con `,`  ejemplo de ello `$MXN1,040.00`

Comment: El prefijo es siempre cuatro caracteres?

Comment: @gbianchi si, siempre son 4

Comment: entonces se arregla con un substring simple.. sacas los primeros cuatro caracteres, y te queda todo lo que viene despues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para sacar de una cadena que siempre tiene el mismo formato, lo mejor es hacer un [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) de la misma, y quedarse con la parte que uno quiere.

En tu caso, se podria hacer asi:

```
str = str.Substring(4);
```

Evitando el problema de la expresión regular, y tambien no teniendo en cuenta si el texto viene en mayusculas o minusculas.

Si la cadena tiene otro formate, esta tecnica no va a funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

No es lo mejor pero no dependes del largo de la cadena

```
static void Main()
    {
        string code = "$MXN1,040.00";


        Program obj = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, 0:C2}", Convert.ToDecimal(obj.extract(code))));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private dynamic extract(string source) {
        var number = default(dynamic);
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            if (source.Substring(i, 1) == ".")
                break;

            if (int.TryParse(source.Substring(i, 1), out int non))
                number += source.Substring(i, 1);

        }
        return number;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias aplicar `regular expression` usando

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "$MXN0.00";
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d.]", "");
        Console.WriteLine(result); 
    }   
}
```